# Formatting DateTime resulting DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I need a function which return a formatted `DateTime`

```
DateTime dt = dateformat("20/01/1988", "dd/MM/yyyy");

DateTime dateformat(string strDt, string strFormat)
{
      return dt;
}
```

In this function (`dateformat()`) we can pass any date and format.

Comment: dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");?

Comment: but its returning string

Comment: [More detail about date-time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: A DateTime is a DateTime and nothing else. You can't format a DateTime. You can for sure format the string representation of the DateTime.

Comment: I think you are looking for [`DateTime.PareExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime` does NOT contain any formating information. You either have a `DateTime`-object containing all the date and time information or a formated `string` containing only the info you selected in the format string.

If you want it the other way around and generate an (unformated) `DateTime` out of a `string` you can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(strDt, strFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Datetime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)    as shown below

```
    string dateString = "20/01/1988"; 
    string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
```

the above code will return **1/20/1988 12:00:00 AM**
so you need to convert it as below as suggested by **chrfin**

```
dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: but I have tried @CarstenKönig with dd/MM/yyyy and it was not giving any exception

Comment: @chrfin i was tried u r fiddle getting answer as  1/20/1988 12:00:00 AM.But i want the answer format become dd/MM/yyyy (20/01/1988)

Comment: @Haris: As already written in my answer: `DateTime` has no formatting information, so you need to supply it to the `ToString` when converting back (see updated fiddle).

Answer (score 1):

**Namespace:**

```
using System.Globalization;
```

**Code:**

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("20/01/1988", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```